# swithing to php pdo, counting rows

Tags: php, pdo

I'm currently in progress of updating all sql queries to pdo where I will use prepare statements to prevent sql injection attacks. So far so good, I'm stuck now in counting rows with pdo. 
I tried following:

```
 $sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM News";
 $STIH = $DBH->query($sqlQuery);
 $rows_affected = $STIH->rowCount();
 echo($rows_affected); // returning result is 1, it should be 1038
```

However, when I'm using old code like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM News";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];
echo ($numrows); // it return result which I expected which is 1038 rows.
```

What I am missing here.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you think that `rowCount` and `fetch_array` do the same thing ?!?

Comment: @tereško think? what's this? PHP is not about thinking. Its about putting codes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$sth->fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to grab the data.

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM News";
$STIH = $DBH->query($sqlQuery);
$rows_affected = $STIH->fetchColumn();
echo ($rows_affected);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused. To get 1038, you want the row's result. Currently, you are getting the number of rows that a SELECT COUNT is returning, which is 1 row, with 1 value in it.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason you are fetching not the data but row count with PDO.
just fetch the data with PDO as you do it with plain mysql

Answer (score 0):

The query is a returning a scalar since you are using `COUNT()`. Since it is a scalar, it only has one row, hence it returns 1. If you want the count of the rows, just use the result of the query.